# Set focus to specific field in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, focus, ms-access-2010

How do I set the focus on a particular field (in this case, the "Ref:" field which is located in the Form Header) when viewing a form in Form View?

Answer (score 3):

You could use SetFocus in Form_Active

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
 yourField.SetFocus
End Sub
```

or you could change the order tab and put your field into first place of the list

Comment: Will this work for elements in the Form Header (as that is where "Ref:" is located)?